# Before merging my pull request can I pull update from release Branch to my feature branch?

Tags: git

Before merging my **feature branch** to **release branch** `update`, can I pull **release branch** `update`? If I took the **release branch** `update` by pull and then again commit/merge my feature, will it create a conflict in **release Branch**?

Comment: In Git, `pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run `git merge` unless I told you to run `git rebase` second instead*. You can run `git fetch` any time you like with no bad side effects. It's the *second* command, `git merge` or `git rebase`, that requires a bit of care. So your question is equivalent to *can I merge from another branch* and the answer to that is always *yes, just make sure you know what you're doing*.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely `pull` the aforementioned update in the `release` branch and then `merge` your `feature` branch. The `pull` may create a merge conflict if there is an update which clashes with the original codebase(say an improvement in a particular code section).

If you `merge` your `feature` branch after this, again, there *may* be a `merge` conflict, which again will depend on the particular case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Not it should not until the same time other person did not push the code into the release branch.

If you are looking for basic  visit this link for in details https://gist.github.com/blackfalcon/8428401